# How to exclude @Value annotation from Jacoco code coverage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, jacoco

I have a class in Spring boot where I am using @Value annotation. In the jacoco reports that line is not getting covered. Even after writing tests that cover all other statements, due to @value annotation the code coverage is being shown as only 10%. How can I exclude @value from jacoco code coverage?